# How to grant identity ApplicationPoolIdentity read rights to folder within my site

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, permissions, identity

On our Windows 2008 R2 server I have a site running under the default ASP.NET v4.0 application pool. The identity of ASP.NET v.4.0 app pool is set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity" (I guess this is default).

How do I grant this identity access to read from a custom folder within my site. I have tried "Application Pool Identity" and "ApplicationPoolIdentity" but both gives me:

> An object named "Application Pool Identity" cannot be found.

Bonus question = should I instead forget about all this and make the change to store the files in app_data folder? Would that solve the issue?

Answer (score 10):

`ICACLS <folder> /grant "IIS AppPool\nameoftheapppool":WRX` did not work for me, it gave an error:

```
Invalid parameter "IIS AppPool\nameoftheapppool"
```

but, the following did work:

```
ICACLS <folder> /grant "IIS AppPool\nameoftheapppool:WRX"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ICACLS tool for this.
The usage herefore is:

`(Command-prompt)> ICACLS <folder> /grant "IIS AppPool\<nameoftheapppool>":WRX`

that should do the trick. ( If you replace the placeholders with the right values )

More information about `ICACLS.exe` can be found here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919240

Comment: Thanks, just tried and not working:

>ICACLS c:\inetpub\webs\mysite\cache\help\pdf  /grant "IIS AppPool\ASP.NET v4.0":WRX

Gives me: Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files but still I get: Access to the path 'cache\help\pdf\' is denied.

Comment: It would help to explain what icacls does (incredibly https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/919240/the-icacls-exe-utility-is-available-for-windows-server-2003-with-servi doesn't mention the words "access control list" anywhere), and importantly what "IIS AppPool\<nameoftheapppool>" is in your example.  Is it an account name?  If so, why can't I search for it when adding access permissions in the NTFS security tab?