# Access to the path Denied after uploading file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I keep receiving the following error message. Please bear with me as i'm fairy new to coding

http://imgur.com/j5twkP

This occurs after trying to upload a file on my website to the database (which is hosted by myLittleAdmin). I have tried granting access rights to my Appdata folder to everyone, network service and all the other usual ones but I still seem to be receiving this message. I'm running visual studio 2013.

can posted more code if needs be

Thanks!

**Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\websites\LocalUser\jheslip02\elmtree\img\2858' is denied.**

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\websites\LocalUser\jheslip02\elmtree\img\2858' is denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

**Source Error:**

Line 47:         {
Line 48:             //then save it to the folder
Line 49:             FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
Line 50:
Line 51:

***Stack Trace:***

[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\websites\LocalUser\jheslip02\elmtree\img\2858' is denied.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +216
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1430
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +205
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) +91
   System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) +160
   Selling.uploadbutton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\websites\LocalUser\jheslip02\elmtree\Selling.aspx.cs:49
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804

Comment: That image link doesn't work.  Please do the hard work of transcribing the messag efor us.

Comment: ... and yes.  Please post more code.  Preferably a [mcve]

Comment: sorry i didnt realise the image wasnt working. Ive copied in the error messages. Thank you!

Comment: Right.  So what has this got to do with C++?  This is clearly a program written in C#.  You might actually get better support on superuser.com, or by adding a win32 tag.

Comment: Usually the problem is because the account running the website doesn't have access. You don't mention which version of IIS is running. If it's anything above 7, websites typically run using an Application Pool Identity. If you have access to the IIS admin, click on the site, then click on "Authentication". Under "Anonymous Authentication" (if enabled), select "Edit" and see which "Anonymous user identity" is being used. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965849/how-to-grant-identity-applicationpoolidentity-read-rights-to-folder-within-my-si